# Bulk email sender and list management API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email

I'm looking for a way to programmatically manage email lists and send large numbers of emails to these lists.  The general idea would be similar to how social networking sites send email notifications when a friend posts new content.  Since a user could have tens of thousands of followers, it doesn't seem realistic to send these directly from my application so I'm curious if there's a good way to handle this through a service provider.  My company is using Google apps but I'm not an expert on their API.  Our environment is ASP.NET MVC.

Any advice is most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/api/) provides API access to their customers, allowing you to manage lists and send out campaigns.

Comment: Looks like you can't create lists from the API, although they DO have a "group" feature to segment a single list into multiple groups.  I'm working with their tech support to determine if that would work in this scenario (each user's followers would be a group within a list).